# Dispaly object of array values in angular 2 using Ngfor

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angular2-template

I have a array of object values.i am using a group by method to group the values based on type.it gives a object of array values.i struggle to how to display the values using Ngfor in angular 2.

i have a following structure value.

```
    {
      [
        {
          id:1
          body:"value1"
          type:"name"
        },
        {
          id:2
          body:"value1"
          type:"id"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          id:3
          body:"value1"
          type:"name"
        },
        {
          id:4
          body:"value1"
          type:"id"
        },
        {
          id:5
          body:"value1"
          type:"name"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          id:6
          body:"value1"
          type:"id"
        },
        {
          id:7
          body:"value1"
          type:"fname"
        },
        {
          id:8
          body:"value1"
          type:"fname"
        }
      ]
   }
```

And my html code is.

```
<div *ngFor="let value of result">
{{value.body}}
</div>
```

Comment: you json seems to be invalid are you sure you have same json data to oprate on?

Comment: sure.after group by i get a same json format.

Comment: @Sakthivel, can you console.log(your_strange_value) ?
and I believe your question should be "how to receive valid JSON out of it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone response.i got a solution for the question.

```
    let value = _.groupBy(data, "type");
    for (let key in value) {
      content.push({ key: key, value: value[key] });
    }
```

and my html is

```
 <div *ngFor="let keys of content">
   <div *ngFor="let value of keys.value">
      {{value.body}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngFor` only works on `Array` element. Also your current JSON seems to invalid. Though You can easily flatten the arrays into single array and use `ngFor` to render it on DOM

```
<div *ngFor="let value of flattenArray">
  {{value.body}}
</div>
```

**Component**

```
flattenArray = [];
//after retrieving result, create flatten array.
for(let value of result){
   this.flattenArray.conact(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have is not an array of objects, it's even not a JSON (check it with https://jsonlint.com/), 
when you replace first {} with [], (and add comas, ofcourse!) all will works fine, here is valid json:

```
[
  [
    {
      id:1,
      body:"value1",
      type:"name"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      body:"value1",
      type:"id"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id:3,
      body:"value1",
      type:"name"
    },
    {
      id:4,
      body:"value1",
      type:"id"
    },
    {
      id:5,
      body:"value1",
      type:"name"
    }
  ]
```

]

and then in angular view:

```
<div *ngFor="let items of result">
     <div *ngFor="let value of items">
        {{value.body}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i use a group by method to group the value..after group by method i got a object of array values only.

Comment: looked attentively,.. gush! you even have no comas in properties list )))
I suppose you have your value as a string? because you definitely can't assign in in JS